# Getting error in showing DialogFragment activity

Tags: java, android

With the below code I am getting this error:

> error:';' expected
> dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog"));

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    Button btnListChild = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btnListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CustomDialogClass dialogFragment = new CustomDialogClass();
            dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog"));
        }
    });

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: What you actually need is to pass fragment manager as first parameter of method show and second one is tag string. So in order to cast fragment manager you should do this.. `((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager()` and all you're missing is some closing braces correctly.

Comment: @JeelVankhede okay, i edited it, now this  error: ';' expected
                dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");

Comment: No that is still not correct syntax, use this: `dialogFragment.show(((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");`

Comment: still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog"));
to dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");

Comment: ` error: cannot find symbol
                dialogFragment.show((Activity) _context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getSupportFragmentManager()
  location: variable _context of type Context `

Comment: Are you using AppCompat theme? If that cast _context to AppCompatActivity